# A clear way to create a combination chart for time series data in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, time-series, data-visualization

I'm a new user of `matplotlib`. I have already learned the basics of plotting data in matplotlib. But I still cannot understand how I can plot multiple time series data as follows:

[image: for example]

It is also important for me that the plot contained a legend.

Data for example:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data_str = '''time        x1   x2  x3  x4   
01.01.1984  100 -50  50  54 
01.02.1984  200 -20  180 7 
01.03.1984  250 -100 150 442413
01.04.1984  300 -50  250 7 
01.05.1984  250 -150 100 403 
01.06.1984  300 -200 100 148 
01.07.1984  200 -100 100 1096'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data_str), delim_whitespace=True)
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%d.%m.%Y')
df = df.set_index('time')

ax = df['x3'].plot(grid=True, figsize=(10, 6), color='tab:grey', linewidth=4)

ax.bar(height=df['x1'], x=df.index, color='tab:blue', width=0.3, zorder=2, label='x1')
ax.bar(height=df['x2'], x=df.index, color='tab:orange', width=0.3, zorder=2, label='x2')

ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.set_yscale('log')
ax2.invert_yaxis()
df['x4'].plot.line(ax=ax2, color='gold', label='x4 (right)', linewidth=4)

ax.axhline(linewidth=1, color='black')
ax.set_xlabel('time', fontsize=16)
plt.xticks(size = 16)
plt.yticks(size = 16)

handles1, labels1 = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
handles2, labels2 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
handles = handles1[1:] + handles1[:1] + handles2 # handles1 is reordered because it uses the line before the bars
labels = labels1[1:] + labels1[:1] + labels2

#order = [0,1,2,3]

ax.legend([handles[idx] for idx in order],[labels[idx] for idx in order],
          loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.2),
          fancybox=True, shadow=True, ncol=5,
          prop={'size': 16})



#plt.xlim(['1983-12-01', '1984-08-01'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explaining each and every step is out of the scope of a stackoverflow answer.  A good starting point are the [online tutorials](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/index.html). Also, the suggested plot is quite complicated for a beginner's plot.

Some examples of functions used:

- `pd.read_csv(filename, ...)` reads in data from a csv file
- `StringIO(data_str)` is a way to mimic a file with reading from a string
- `plt.subplots` creates a figure (`fig`) and subplots (referred to as `ax`) to plot on
- `df['x1'].plot.bar(...)` is a way to plot a bar plot with pandas
- `df['x3'].plot.line(...)` is a way to plot a line plot with pandas
- `ax1.twinx()` creates the y-axis at the right
- ...

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data_str = '''time        x1   x2  x3  x4   
01.01.1984  100 -50  50  54 
01.02.1984  200 -20  180 7 
01.03.1984  250 -100 150 442413
01.04.1984  300 -50  250 7 
01.05.1984  250 -150 100 403 
01.06.1984  300 -200 100 148 
01.07.1984  200 -100 100 1096'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data_str), delim_whitespace=True)
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 4))
ax1.axhline(0, color='black', lw=2) # draw a long horizontal line at y=0
df = df.set_index('time')
df['x1'].plot.bar(ax=ax1, color='skyblue', label='x1')
df['x2'].plot.bar(ax=ax1, color='darkorange', label='x2')
df['x3'].plot.line(ax=ax1, color='slategray', label='x3')
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.set_yscale('log')
df['x4'].plot.line(ax=ax2, color='gold', label='x4 (right)')

handles1, labels1 = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
handles2, labels2 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
handles = handles1[1:] + handles1[:1] + handles2 # handles1 is reordered because it uses the line before the bars
labels = labels1[1:] + labels1[:1] + labels2
ax1.legend(handles, labels, loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.1), ncol=len(handles))
ax1.set_xlabel('')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: combined bar and line plot]

Comment: When I try to add a grid to [your graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abjsP.png), for some reason the grid is not displayed relative to the y axis (only x). In addition, the grid is superimposed on the chart itself, not displayed behind it. It seems that in this situation `excell` has better visualization capabilities than `matplotlib`)

Comment: Moreover, your code does not work correct if the index of the data frame is in date format (`df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])`)

Comment: Well, you need to choose whether you want the grid going with the left or with the right y-axis, as they don't have ticks at the same position. Please don't compare software just with one optimized example that coincidentally works well with the defaults of one trying to mimic with the other.  If you want a specific format for your dates, you can convert them back to strings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It turned out to be very valuable to me. I almost reproduced the identical diagram in the `matplotlib`. But all the same, in `excel`, the diagram looks a little neater. I don't know how else I can improve my diagram to make it look better.

Comment: A problem is that pandas gets quite confused when combining plots with dates.  If possible, convert the dates to the exact text format you want to use.  Note that pandas bar plots are always categorical (equidistant bars), while line plots try to be numerical (except when the x-values are strings).

Answer (score 1):

A simple way of plotting multiple series in one plot (from a Pandas Data Frame, df), using a second y-axis is as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 
                   'x1':[100, 200, 250, 300, 250, 300, 200],
                   'x2':[-50,-20,-100,-50, -150, -200, -100],
                   'x3':[50, 180, 150, 250, 100, 100, 100],
                   'x4':[54, 7, 442413, 7, 403, 148, 1096]})

plt.figure()
df.x1.plot.bar()
df.x2.plot.bar(color='red')
df.x3.plot.line(color='red')
df.x4.plot.line(color='green', secondary_y=True)
```

[image]